# Number of Comparisons for Heap Sort

Tags: c, algorithm, heapsort

I wrote some C code to analyze the number of comparisons and runtime of building a heap and running heapsort. However, I'm not sure if the output of my code makes sense. Heapsort should perform at O(n log n), but the number of comparisons I'm seeing doesn't seem to be very close to that. For example, for an input of size n = 100, I'm seeing ~200 comparisons to build the heap and ~800 comparisons in heap sort. Am I just analyzing the data wrong, or is there something wrong with the way I'm collecting comparisons in my code?

I can provide a link to github if it would make a difference for anyone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

void bottom_up_heap_sort(int*, int);
void heap_sort(int*, int);
void sift_up(int*, int);
void sift_down(int*, int);
void build_max_heap(int*, int); 
void bottom_up_build_max_heap(int*, int);
void randomize_in_place(int*, int);
int* generate_array(int);
void swap(int*, int*);
int cmp(int, int);
void print_array(int*, int);

int heapsize;
unsigned long comparison_counter;
clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;

int main() {
    int k, N;
    int* A;
    int* B;
    int i;

    printf("Testing Sift_Down Heap Sort\n");
    for(k = 2; k <= 5; k++) {
        comparison_counter = 0;
        N = (int)pow((double)10, k);

        begin = clock();
        A = generate_array(N);
        end = clock();
        time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("Time Spent Generating Array: %f\n", time_spent);

        // print the first unsorted array
        //printf("Unsorted Array:\n");
        //print_array(A, N);

        begin = clock();
        // call heap_sort on the first unsorted array
        heap_sort(A, N);
        end = clock();
        time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        // show that the array is now sorted
        //printf("Sorted array: \n");
        //print_array(A, N);
        printf("Done with k = %d\n", k);
        printf("Comparisons for Heap Sort: %lu\n", comparison_counter);
        printf("Time Spent on Heap Sort: %f\n", time_spent);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("----------------------------------\n");
    printf("Testing Sift_Up Heap Sort\n");
        for(k = 2; k <= 5; k++) {
        comparison_counter = 0;
                N = (int)pow((double)10, k);

        begin = clock();
                B = generate_array(N);
        end = clock();
        time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("Time Spent Generating Array: %f\n", time_spent);

                // print the unsorted array
                //printf("Unsorted Array:\n");
                //print_array(B, N);

        begin = clock();
                // call heap_sort on the unsorted array
                bottom_up_heap_sort(B, N);
        end = clock();
        time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

                // show that the array is now sorted
                //printf("Sorted array: \n");
                //print_array(B, N);
                printf("Done with k = %d\n", k);
        printf("Comparisons for Heap Sort: %lu\n", comparison_counter);
        printf("Time Spent on Heap Sort: %f\n", time_spent);
        printf("\n");
        }

    printf("----------------------------------\n");

    return 0;
}

void bottom_up_heap_sort(int* arr, int len) {
    int i;

    // build a max heap from the bottom up using sift up
    bottom_up_build_max_heap(arr, len);
    printf("Comparisons for heap construction: %lu\n", comparison_counter);
    comparison_counter = 0; 
    for(i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // swap the last leaf and the root
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[0]);
        // remove the already sorted values
        len--;
        // repair the heap
        bottom_up_build_max_heap(arr, len);
    }
}

void heap_sort(int* arr, int len) {
    int i;

    // build a max heap from the array
    build_max_heap(arr, len);
    printf("Comparisons for heap construction: %lu\n", comparison_counter);
    comparison_counter = 0;
    for(i = len-1; i >= 1; i--) {
        swap(&arr[0], &arr[i]); // move arr[0] to its sorted place
        // remove the already sorted values
        heapsize--;
        sift_down(arr, 0);  // repair the heap
    }
}

void sift_down(int* arr, int i) {
    int c = 2*i+1;
    int largest;

    if(c >= heapsize) return;

    // locate largest child of i
    if((c+1 < heapsize) && cmp(arr[c+1], arr[c]) > 0) {
        c++;
    }

    // if child is larger than i, swap them
    if(cmp(arr[c], arr[i]) > 0) {
        swap(&arr[c], &arr[i]);
        sift_down(arr, c);
    }
}

void sift_up(int* arr, int i) {
    if(i == 0) return; // at the root

    // if the current node is larger than its parent, swap them
    if(cmp(arr[i], arr[(i-1)/2]) > 0) {
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[(i-1)/2]);
        // sift up to repair the heap
        sift_up(arr, (i-1)/2);
    }
}

void bottom_up_build_max_heap(int* arr, int len) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sift_up(arr, i);
    }
}

void build_max_heap(int* arr, int len) {
    heapsize = len;
    int i;
    for(i = len/2; i >= 0; i--) {
        // invariant: arr[k], i < k <= n are roots of proper heaps
        sift_down(arr, i);
    }
}

void randomize_in_place(int* arr, int n) {
    int j, k;
    double val;
    time_t t;
    // init the random number generator
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    // randomization code from class notes
    for(j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
        val = ((double)random()) / 0x7FFFFFFF;
        k = j + val*(n-j);
        swap(&arr[k], &arr[j]);
    }
}

// this function is responsible for creating and populating an array 
// of size k, and randomizing the locations of its elements
int* generate_array(int k) {
    int* arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*k-1);
    int i, j, x, N;
    double val;
    time_t t;
    // init the random number generator
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));

    // fill the array with values from 1..N
    for(i = 0; i <= k-1; i++) {
        arr[i] = i+1;
    }

    N = (int)pow((double)10, 5);
    // randomize the elements of the array for 10^5 iterations
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        randomize_in_place(arr, k);
    }

    return arr;
}

// swap two elements
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int cmp(int a, int b) {
    comparison_counter++;

    if(a > b) return 1;
    else if(a < b) return -1;
    else return 0;
}

// print out an array by iterating through
void print_array(int* arr, int size) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual number for such small values of n doesn't really matter, as the constant factors are omitted in the complexity. What matters is the growth of your algorithm, measuring for increasingly larger values of n, and plotting them should give roughly the same graph as your theoretical complexity.

I tried your code for a couple of n, and the increase in complexity was approximately O(n logn )

Comment: So as long as it's roughly the same magnitude it's accurate enough? That's good to know. I was worried that the values weren't close enough, but I guess comparing asymptotically is a little looser.

Answer (score 1):

`O(n log n)` (or in general `O(f(x))`) does not give you any idea about the expected value at a single point.

That's because big-O notation ignores constant factors. In other words, all of `n * log(n)`, `0.000001 * n * log(n)` and `1000000 * n * log(n)` are in `O(n log n)`. So the result for a particular value of `n` is completely undetermined.

What you can deduce from big-O notation is the effect of modify the control variable. If a function involves `O(n)` operations, then it is expected that doubling `n` will double the number of operations. If a function involves `O(n2)` operations, then it is expected that doubling `n` will quadruple the number of operations. And so on.